# Securing controller PHP (MVC)

Tags: php, security

I know dynamically loading requested classes is extremely insecure, but it does save alot of complexity in my code...

Is this consider secure, or is there a way for the user to exploit this?
this is my code:

```
$currentPage = Classes\stdlib::GetVariable("view"); //Gets a variable from $_GET and escapes it...
$isAdmin = isset($_GET["admin"]);
$view = "";
$content = null;
$allowedViews = array("Admin","Brukere","Fag","Fravær","Kontakt","Login","Profil","Registrer");
if (in_array($currentPage,$allowedViews,true)) {
    $view = "Views\\$currentPage";
    $content = new $view(); // <--- This is usualy unsecure since its derived from user request
}

//Using $content later in the code....
```

This basically just loads the class if it is allowed (in_array).

What do you guys think? Major security hole or OK?

Comment: autoloading classes isn't insecure, AS LONG as you don't let users directly specify them. e.g. `include($_GET['foo'])`

Comment: Your code seems fine: you have an array of valid views to be used, and  check against it. I guess later on you process the case when the requested view *is not* in the array, and have your script bail out.

Comment: Thnks, that was quick! Yep, if no valid View is selected it goes to a default one, but I will include a logging function t odetect if someone is trying some funny buisniss :P

Comment: You need to look at an autoloader. And as others have mentioned, auto-loading’s fine, so long as you don’t do it based directly on user input (i.e. `new Vendor/Package/{$_GET[key]}Controller`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc B. said including files with code like `include($_GET['foo'])` **is not secure**, because it is a file inclusion vulnerability. For example an attacker can upload a completely valid image file with PHP code in it and include it with this code by changing the value if the `$_GET['foo']`. So you can use `include()` only after you validated the input. There are several ways to do that, for example

```
$map = array('bar' => 'bar.php');
if (!isset($map[$_GET['foo']]))
    throw new \Exception();
include($map[$_GET['foo']]);
```

or simply with an if-else

```
if ($_GET['foo'] == 'bar')
    include('bar.php');
else
    throw new \Exception();
```

Using autoload solves the same problem. It defines a rule how to build a class - file map, so it has a lower risk. For example by **this vulnerable code**:

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];
$bar = new $foo();
$bar->doSomething();
```

he can only check what classes are available in your system, and probably use an available class against you with the `doSomething()` method. Which is still a security risk ofc, but not as huge as a file inclusion would be.

So by using classes you should do the same mapping or if-else as I wrote down at the beginning:

```
if ($_GET['foo'] == 'bar' && $_SESSION['isAdmin'])
    $view = new Views\AdminView();
else
    $view = new Views\RegularView();
$view ->doSomething();
```

I don't think having a list of allowed view classes is a best practice. I think you should do the authorization before querying your data. By rendering a view you usually already got some data from a database or from a file, but we don't want users without authorization to send that query, because it is completely superfluous and just eats up resources on the server.

In your code `$isAdmin = isset($_GET["admin"]);` is very strange. Everybody can set that parameter, so using it to decide whether somebody is an admin would be a very huge design flaw. Every variable coming from `$_GET` or `$_POST` can be faked (except OAuth request signatures and CSRF tokens :D). Try to learn more about sessions, authentication and authorization, and if you have further questions about security, you should ask it here: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi inf3rno, thanks for a great answer! the isset(admin) thing is just to simplify rendering of my menu, so if that is set in the request, the admin dropdown is set to active :P Should probably change that so that the view's themselfs decide if it is a admin view... I am having a hard time figuring out the best way to design all the views, and often just fall back to letting index.php handle all the work. I need to look into that more... Anyway, thanks for a great informative answer! :)